# Efficient way to filter IEnumerable and serilize it to JSON in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, json, ienumerable

I am working on a test project that reads data from `DB`, filters the result, and send it back as `JSON` message to `DataTable`.
It takes around 5 second for 10-15 rows of data, So I wonder something might be wrong here.
I checked it in debug mode and saw this following lines (filtering `IEnum`) takes so long.

```
var result1 = new
{
    draw = Draw,
    recordsTotal = persons.Count(),
    recordsFiltered = persons.Count(),
    data = persons
    .Where(p => p.FName.Contains(sSearch, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || p.LName.Contains(sSearch, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || p.Id.ToString().Contains(sSearch, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || p.Email.Contains(sSearch, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    .Select(p => new[] {p.Email,})
    .Skip(iDisplayStart)   
    .Take(iDisplayLength)
};
```

I deleted the search part ("where") and tested it again but still take around 4.5 sec.
Another thing which takes around 1-2 sec is `JSON` serializer:

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var json = serializer.Serialize(result1);
context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
context.Response.Write(json);
```

Please help if you know what are the best practices.

Comment: are you using ASP.NET MVC ?

Comment: Why are you using `persons.Count()` for both the total and filtered numbers?

Comment: What is `persons`? Is it possible that every enumeration of `persons` results in DB access?

Comment: @KishoreSahas its ASP web form

Comment: @JonSkeet I corrected that, but it didn't make it faster as expected

Comment: @shay__ Person is an object that has firstname lastname id and email. I didn't quite understand your secont question, please explain more

Comment: @azizib Can you show us the declaration of `persons`?

Comment: @shay__  yes sure: 'var persons = Person.GetPersons(AdminUsername);'

Comment: public static IEnumerable<Person> GetPersons(){
   using ( DB_Entities DB = new DB_Entities()){
   foreach (Username x in u.Client.Usernames){
           string id = x.EmployeeID;
                                string fn = x.FirstName;
                                string ln = x.LastName;
                                string em = x.UsernameEmail; yield return new Person { Id = id, FName = fn, LName = ln, Email = em};
                            
                        }  
  } 
 }

Comment: @azizib But what is DB_Entites? Is it a data access object? If so, keep in mind that Linq is lazy, and it consumes the data only **and every time** it is called for. So every time you perform `.Count()`, you might be causing a new database query. if that is your case, it is easily solved by fetching the data first, like `var persons = Person.GetPersons(AdminUsername).ToList();` (mind the **ToList()** at the end).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not knowing what "persons" is exactly I would just make the following suggestions.

```
var result1 = new
{
    draw = Draw,
    recordsTotal = persons.Count(),
    recordsFiltered = (iDisplayLength - iDisplayStart),
    data = persons
        .Where(p => InString(p.FName) || InString(p.LName) || InString(p.Id.ToString()) || InString(p.Email))
        .Select(p => new { Email = p.Email }) //already a list, does not need to be an array of objects
        .Skip(iDisplayStart)   
        .Take(iDisplayLength)
        .ToList() //execute
};

//also consider an extension method
public bool InString(string prop, string search)
{
    return prop.Contains(search, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
}
```

Comment: Thanks Stephen, It made it better and I can see the difference when I publish it , even though its not working perfect yet (I need to debug to find more detail ). interesting point is it made JSON Serializer much faster.
Thanks

Comment: BTW Person is an object that has firstname lastname id and email.
I've heard that ENUM is more efficient than List (as I used Yield method when generating ENUM of person), why chaniging ENUM to List supposed to make it faster?